# Is the space $(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q},d)$ separable with the metric $d(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, separable-spaces

Is the space $(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q},d)$ separable with the metric $d(x,y)=\dfrac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$?

Here is what I think: The set of irrational numbers are uncountable. Since we cannot approximate any element from that space with a countable family of sets, it follows that the space is not separable. However, I could not relate this to the given metric.

Another proposition to prove the separability of the space is to use the fact that $(X,d)$ is separable iff $\forall \varepsilon$ $\exists$ countable $\varepsilon-$net.

How can I dis/prove the separability of the metric space?

Comment: You did not use that formula at all in your argument.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is second countable, hence so is every subspace (in the subspace topology).

Comment: I know, because I couldn't relate this to the given metric above. Well, I have actually no idea how to show this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

First notice that $d$ induces the standard Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

Then consider the countable set
$$\mathbb{Q} + \sqrt2 = \{q+\sqrt{2} : q \in \mathbb{Q}\}$$
and show that it is dense in $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: So if I show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and state that $\forall (q+\sqrt2)$ is a shifted element of $\mathbb{Q}$ by $\sqrt{2}$ such that it is in       $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. Would that work?

Comment: @studios.93 Yes, pretty much. For $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ let $(q_n)_n$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $q_n \to x - \sqrt{2}$ (this sequence exists since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$). Then $(q_n+\sqrt{2})_n$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{Q}+\sqrt{2}$ converging to $x$.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarification.